# Make QTreeWidgetItem unique among siblings

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside

Is there some way to make sure that updating an existing `QTreeWidgetItem` or inserting a new one ensures that the item is unique among its siblings based on the value of a single column?

I have tried to do something like this with a `QTreeView` and my own custom model and have gotten it to work, but some advanced features like moving items with drag and drop are eluding me. I figure, the `QTreeWidget` and `QTreeWidgetItem` classes ought to get more of this type of stuff for free and ought to cause me fewer headaches throughout. However, I still need to be able to guarantee uniqueness if I go the `QTreeWidget` route. Can this be done? If so, how?

**NOTE**:

I am using PySide, but I marked this question as PyQt as well since most solutions cross over between the two without much fuss.

Comment: It has been so long. But for anyone interested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443129/pyqt-validity-check-on-qtreewidgetitem/54452709#54452709) might be helpful.